# Pulling value from form, then converting text to integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, parseint

I've been trying to use jQuery to pull a variable from my form (as a string) and then convert it into a number to have it added to other variables. Instead, NaN is displayed.

```
<input type="text" name="donation" id="donation" value="0">

var donation = parseInt(form.find('input[text=donation]'), 10);
```

Used jQuery in the past, but still new to some aspects. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your first selector is wrong, it is trying to find a input with a text attribute of donation, what you meant was either 'input[type=text]' or 'input[name=donation]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps because `#donaton` should be `#donation`?

Comment: Actually realized I copied and pasted that wrong. Still gives me NaN.

Comment: @JoshTate take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ecTYq/ .

ParseInt works on your  $('#donation').val() . Watch how it correctly adds your textbox value of 5 to the starting "total" of 5 and ends up with 10 as expected.

Comment: That works perfectly @Tor. Is there any pro/con's to not using jQuery's form.find in this case?

Comment: @Josh Traditionally if you know the unique id of an element, $('#id') is the easiest way of finding it, and already searches your whole page. I've used .find() almost as a way of further filtering a selection down and searching within a selection's descendants. 

As for "form" - it's not a known object within the scope of the code you pasted. Is form something you're defining higher up in your code that we can't see?

Comment: @Thor Yes, sorry for not showing that. I have it declared up top, `var form = $('#member_form');`. Thanks for the information too. Really new to this, still learning what I can over jQuery.

Comment: @Josh In that case, using form.find() is fine because you're already searching the "form"'s descendants for something. What doesn't make sense about your selector ('input[text=donation]') is that your input has no "text" attribute. it does have "name" and "id" attributes however. And when you're going by an id attribute, the shortcut again is #[youridhere]. Secondly, as Neil shows below, you're running parseInt on the found element, not the element's value. That's why you need .val() to grab the value attribute from the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var donation = parseInt($('#donation').val(), 10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U96F3/1/